# Trying to parse a text file and capture line above in Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, datetime, text

What I'm attempting to accomplish is read a 15MB text file every 5 seconds as it gets written to from another program. I'm able to accomplish that and read it line by line. What I'm running into an issue with is the actual logs are split on two lines. The first being a timestamp and the second being the Info flag.

As I read the text file line by line I'm looking for a list of certain words and if true I need it to return the corresponding timestamp from the line above. The method I'm using right now isn't working as it's having to search line by line, and then within that loop if true that it found something important it's searching again for the line above.. then I'll need to read the string for the timestamp and generate a datetime object out of it too.

Here's what the text looks like

```
Sep 1, 2013 8:58:05 AM LaunchingApplet
INFO: THIS IS A FLAG MESSAGE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the previous line in a variable:

```
the_file = open('test.txt','r')
prev = None
for line in the_file:
    if line.strip()== 'INFO: THIS IS A FLAG MESSAGE':
        tokens = prev.split(' ')
        date_str = ' '.join(tokens[0:5])
        message = tokens[5:]
        the_date = datetime.strptime(date_str,'%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        print the_date, message
    prev = line.strip()
```

Comment: I think `if line.strip() == ...` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

as a file is iterable,

```
with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "INFO: THIS IS A FLAG MESSAGE" in f.next(): print line
```

will work for you as well

Comment: I thought that was intentional- that the input was set up as pairs of lines such that the first line was a datestamp and the second was the status line.  If that is not the case, then this will not work for this case after all.